# How to get Browser Information + Time Stamp with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function, which will execute on user login. It should get the browser, OS, resolution and time currently on user's PC?

Is it even possible to obtain such info and how?

Comment: did you do any research before posting this?

Comment: Yes, here on stackoverflow and google search. Found only how to get IP and hostname :S

Comment: Is the PHP running on a server or locally on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

[source1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

There are other parameters in $_SERVER super global variable that you might find helpful as well such as time info. [check for that here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

GetDate() for getting date

```
<?php
$today = getdate(); <---- In correct (updated below)
print_r($today);
?>
```

[source2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

### Updated Answer

You cannot get browser time from PHP because PHP runs on the server. It knows nothing about client and is completely ignorant of client time. But you can use JavaScript inside PHP and hack the browser time, like this

```
echo "<script type=\\"text/javascript\\">";
    echo "localtime = new Date();";
    echo "document.location.href = '$PHP_SELF?client_time=' + localtime.getTime();";
    echo "</script>";
```

[More on this on sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/displaying-client-time-with-php/1677/2)

Comment: browscap ini directive not set... Is that the only way to get browser?

Comment: this should work if your php is properly configured.

Comment: `getdate()` does not provide *"time currently on user's PC"*

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks. corrected answer.

Answer (score 3):

PHP will only give server time, to get the user's pc time you have to use javascript

```
  function getTime()
    {
    var d = new Date();
    var c_hour = d.getHours();
    var c_min = d.getMinutes();
    var c_sec = d.getSeconds();
    var t = c_hour + ":" + c_min + ":" + c_sec;
    return t;
    }
```