# Using php to identify a the timezone of a user to show a banner on my website

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a banner on my website that states: "we are available monday- friday 7am to 6pm est [call now]" I would like to use php to identify the time zone the user is in and display the banner on the page only if the user is on the website during our hours of opperation.

Essentially the banner will be used to prompt the user to make a phone call. The issue is that we dont want users to call when we are unavailable, and therefore would like to hide it from users in all time zones if they are on our site while we are closed.

Is it possible to get this done using php? I am not very experienced with this programing language and appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Browser Information + Time Stamp with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247038/how-to-get-browser-information-time-stamp-with-php)

Comment: Your approach is wrong. If you *"are available monday- friday 7am to 6pm **EST**"* then it does not matter what timezone the client is in. You're only concerned with hours of operation with regards to Eastern Standard Time. Use the server time, and display an image if it's between 7am-6pm **EST**

Comment: [this is basically what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15911349/4233593)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');//it is your country
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

this is your current datetime. Set it in your code.

Comment: (Not downvoter) I think you code sets server timezone. Hosangja wants to detect clients timezome

Comment: exactly. I was thinking that i could get it from the uses ip address. is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for yor description @PriyeshKumar

Comment: I think getting IP first is step of what you want @Hosangja

Comment: This is the correct approach for the problem. It does not matter what timezone the client is in since hours of operation are in EST. Use the server time. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/63198320)

Comment: nice @JeffPuckettII